# Room insert not trigger the Flow

Tags: kotlin, android-room, kotlin-flow

in viewModel, I subscribe to a flow that calls the database (by Room). But when I insert data, the flow does not return updated data.

View model function that subscribes:

```
fun initData(tournamentId: Long) {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        tournamentRepository.getStream(tournamentId).map { it?.toModel() }
            .collect { tournament ->
                if (tournament != null) {
                    participantRepository.getAllByTournament(tournamentId)
                        .map { it.map { it.playerId } }.collect { playersId ->
                            playerRepository.getAllByIds(playersId)
                                .map { it.map { it.toModel() } }
                                .collect { players ->
                                    println(players)
                                    _uiState.value = _uiState.value.copy(
                                        tournament = _uiState.value.tournament.copy(
                                            id = tournament.id,
                                            type = tournament.type,
                                            name = tournament.name,
                                            players = players
                                        )
                                    )
                                }
                        }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

View model function that inserts:

```
fun addUser() {
    viewModelScope.launch {
        val idPlayer: Long =
            playerRepository.insert(
                PlayerEntity(
                    name = "Player${_uiState.value.tournament.players.size + 1}",
                    guest = true
                )
            )
        participantRepository.insert(
            ParticipantEntity(
                tournamentId = _uiState.value.tournament.id,
                playerId = idPlayer
            )
        )
    }
}
```

participant repository:

```
class OfflinePlayerRepository(private val playerDao: PlayerDao):PlayerRepository {
override fun getAllStream(): Flow<List<PlayerEntity>> = playerDao.getAllItems()
override fun getStream(id: Long): Flow<PlayerEntity?> = playerDao.getItem(id)
override suspend fun insert(player: PlayerEntity):Long = playerDao.insert(player)
override suspend fun insertAll(players: List<PlayerEntity>): List<Long> = playerDao.insertAll(players)
override suspend fun delete(player: PlayerEntity) = playerDao.delete(player)
override suspend fun update(player: PlayerEntity) = playerDao.update(player)
override fun getAllByIds(ids: List<Long>): Flow<List<PlayerEntity>> = playerDao.getAllByIds(ids)
override suspend fun deleteById(id: Long) = playerDao.deleteById(id)
}
```

participant Dao:

```
@Dao
interface PlayerDao {
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun insert(player: PlayerEntity):Long
@Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
suspend fun insertAll(players: List<PlayerEntity>):List<Long>
@Update
suspend fun update(player: PlayerEntity)
@Delete
suspend fun delete(player: PlayerEntity)
@Query("SELECT * from players WHERE id = :id")
fun getItem(id: Long): Flow<PlayerEntity>
@Query("SELECT * from players ORDER BY name ASC")
fun getAllItems(): Flow<List<PlayerEntity>>
@Query("SELECT * from players where id in(:ids) ORDER BY name ASC")
fun getAllByIds(ids:List<Long>): Flow<List<PlayerEntity>>
@Query("DELETE FROM players WHERE id=:id")
suspend fun deleteById(id: Long)
}
```

What should I change so that this flow returns data when I add a player?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flows from Room are infinite. They monitor the database for changes, so they never reach a last item and finish being collected.

Your problem is your use of nested `collect` calls on infinite flows. When you call `collect` on an infinite flow, it never returns because it's always waiting for another emission. So when you collect inside a collect, it the outer lambda will never get past the first item.

First, you're unnecessarily upcasting this to a nullable type, which is making your downstream code have to do null checks, so in your repo change

```
override fun getStream(id: Long): Flow<PlayerEntity?> = playerDao.getItem(id)
```

to

```
override fun getStream(id: Long): Flow<PlayerEntity> = playerDao.getItem(id)
```

To avoid these `map` and nested `collect` calls, you can use `flatMapLatest` and `combine`. `flatMapLatest` is using nested `collect` calls under the hood, but it automatically cancels them when new source flow values are emitted. In your ViewModel:

```
fun initData(tournamentId: Long) {
    val tournaments = tournamentRepository.getStream(tournamentId)
    val playerModels = participantRepository.getAllByTournament(tournamentId)
        .map { participants -> participants.map { it.playerId } } 
        .flatMapLatest { playerIdsList -> playerRepository.getAllByIds(playerIdsList) }
        .map { playersList -> playersList.map { it.toModel } }

    tournaments.combine(playerModels) { tourney, playerModels ->
        Log.i("MyViewModel", playerModels)
        val newTournament = _uiState.value.tournament.copy(
                id = tourney.id,
                type = tourney.type,
                name = tourney.name,
                players = playerModels
            )
        _uiState.value = _uiState.value.copy(tournament = newTournament)
        Unit // not sure if this line is necessary
    }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
}
```

By the way, I think this would all be considerably simpler if you used a single database so you could use SQL JOIN operations (which are easy to do in Room, [see here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/relationships)) to get your flow of tournaments with players directly from your DAO.

Comment: Thank you, it's work. The Unit line is effectively redundant. I use one database. I just learned Kotkin step by step. I will see the link.